# send email with specified name as from address in ci

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I am using CI

I send email using CI library. Its working fine.
I want a slight change. When i send email from abc@test.com. then the inbox title abc. i want to change that to 'scheduler'.

Eg:

```
        $this->email->to('adarsh@gmail.com');
        $this->email->from('abc@test.com');
        $this->email->subject('Meeting Reminder');
```

After sending the mail. The inbox display abc as heading. Iwant to change it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
$this->email->from('abc@test.com',"Scheduler"); # can use Single quote('Scheduler') as well
```

Comment: heading is abc@test.com. Not scheduler

Comment: No. im working with it. Single quotes also didnt help ??

Comment: @AdarshMPallickal delete your old recived messages and try again

Comment: @AdarshMPallickal HAPPY TO HELP :)